# Populate string as boolean in CheckboxType in Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, symfony5

I'm persisting many to one relation into mysql, but i'm facing an issue with populating checkboxType in update function because I stored all CheckBoxType as string in MySQl.

I tried following ,but it didn't worked.

```
    $data = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Item::class)->find($id);
    $sizes = filter_var($size, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
    $form = $this->createForm(ItemType::class, $data);
```

Following is the class:

item

```
  /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $price;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Size::class, inversedBy="items" , cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $sizes;

     /******************/

    public function getSizes(): ?Size
{
    return $this->sizes;
}

public function setSizes(?Size $sizes): self
{
    $this->sizes = $sizes;

    return $this;
}
```

Size

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Item::class, mappedBy="sizes")
 */
private $items;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->items = new ArrayCollection();
}


public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getS(): ?string
{
    return $this->s;
}

public function setS(string $s): self
{
    $this->s = $s;

    return $this;
}
```

I should have made boolean ,but is there any way to get away from the following error??

> Unable to transform value for property path "s": Expected a Boolean.

Comment: Please add your formType, the complete controller action(s) where the form is handled and, the column definition for the property path "s"

Comment: I don't understand your posted code but a [data transformer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html) can take care of transforming strings to boolean and vice versa.  But I suspect you are actually asking something different than the title seems to suggest.